# Kodos & "cannot refer to open group"

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to only match 1010 or 0101 but nor 1111 nor 0000.
I use the following regex :

```
\b((1|0)(?!\2))+
```

It works well in Kodos but I also want the matched sequence thanks to group().
I've tried :

```
\b(((1|0)(?!\2))+)
```

but "cannot refer to open group*" is displayed in Kodos 
and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Please can you help me ?

Edit: The appropriate regex is `(\b(((1|0)(?!\3))+)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you have three separate groups in your second code line. They are numbered based on the ordering of the opening parens.

```
Group 1: ((1|0)(?!\2))+
Group 2: (1|0)(?!\2)
Group 3: 1|0
```

As you can see, group 2 contains a reference to itself, but it is still open while being parsed.

Comment: Thanks. I better understand the problem with your help. I must change the regex or changing parens will be enought ?

Comment: Well, since you added the extra pair of parens, all you have to do is adjust the group accordingly. The `\2` should be `\3` with the extra group.