# How to handle "cannot refer to an open group at position" in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, tokenize

With modified code taken from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer), in the tokenizer below I have added regular expression to match docstrings, comments and quotes which are combined into a single master regular expression and successive matches are looped over.

```
import collections
import re

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    keywords = {'IF', 'THEN', 'ENDIF', 'FOR', 'NEXT', 'GOSUB', 'RETURN'}
    token_specification = [

        ('DOC',   r'([\'"]{3})[^\x00]*?\2'),              # docstrings
        ('COMM',  r'#.*'),                                # comments
        ('QUOT',  r'(?:"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|'   # quotes
                  r'\'([^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')|'
                  r'r\'([^"(]*)\((.*?)\)\4\'')
    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        if kind == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = mo.end()
            line_num += 1
        elif kind == 'SKIP':
            pass
        elif kind == 'MISMATCH':
            raise RuntimeError('%r unexpected on line %d' % (value, line_num))
        else:
            if kind == 'ID' and value in keywords:
                kind = value
            column = mo.start() - line_start
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)

statements = '''
    """docstr1

    blah"""
    \'''docstr2\'''
    # ok
    IF "okkk" and 'ole' quantity THEN
        total := total + price * quantity;
        tax := price * 0.05;
    ENDIF;
'''

for token in tokenize(statements):
    print(token)
```

The above gives the following error:

```
line 72, in <module>
    for token in tokenize(statements),
line 44, in tokenize
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code),
line 220, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string),
line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags),
line 536, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags),
line 829, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0),
line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state)),
line 778, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state),
line 437, in _parse_sub
   itemsappend(_parse(source, state)),
line 524, in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state),
line 415, in _escape
    len(escape)) sre_constants.error: cannot refer to an open group at position 142
```

I understand that the problem is the fact that the `QUOT` regex should be matched before the other two regexes (*in case this is too simplistic or plain wrong please do explain*).

I am afraid that on some occasions I may end up messing the order of the regexes and not being able to get an error in order to fix it until I provide an appropriate `statements`.

My question is **how could I be able to handle such cases/errors gracefully?** Is there a `try .. except` approach appropriate? Any code example to illustrate this would be great.

(*using Python 3.5.1*)

Comment: See if you can relate to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511083/kodos-cannot-refer-to-open-group

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Not sure how that can help me handle the error although useful.