# Regex to match m a's followed by n b's with m > n > 0

Tags: python, regex

How to match strings of the form

```
"a"*m + "b"*n
```

With the constraint that `m > n > 0`.

Example matches:

```
aab
aaabb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbb
```

Example non-matches (violating the m > n constraint):

```
abb
aabb
aaaabbbb
```

I was able to do this in perl by using a [recursive subpattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?PARNO)-(?-PARNO)-(?+PARNO)-(?R)-(?0)). But in Python that feature doesn't work:

```
>>> re.match("^a+(a(?1)?b)$", "aaabb")
error: unknown extension ?1 at position 6
```

Is there any way to do this in stdlib Python `re` module, or is there another pattern possible which doesn't require an external PCRE library?

Comment: Did you try using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, but the question asks about stdlib Python `re` ("_...which doesn't require an external PCRE library_")

Comment: @wim You are right, I was too fast with my comment. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: "No" is an acceptable answer, if it comes with evidence that recursive pattern is _required_ here and Python `re` can't match this some other way with a single pattern (no pre-processing)

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a single regexp. I don't think there's any way to make the number of repetitions in `{x,y}` variable, or to capture the number of repetitions of a pattern (to implement the `m > n` relationship).

Comment: There's a language agnostic solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644267/589924), but it doesn't work in Python

Comment: Is the expression actually regular?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I think it is not regular, but neither are modern re engines

Comment: Perhaps like this `^a+(?:a(?=a*(\1?b)))+\1$` https://regex101.com/r/qHkBdy/1

Comment: The practical context in which this came up was [AoC day 19: Monster Messages](https://github.com/wimglenn/advent-of-code-wim/blob/0949da9f07787386ddee2e7f9370aa21ab53e153/aoc_wim/aoc2020/q19.py#L48-L50), where 'a' and 'b' are not single characters but actually much larger capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to match 1 or more a's at the beginning to match more a's than b's, and use a repeating group 1+ more times to match at least a single b to match the a > b rule.

```
^a+(?:a(?=a*(\1?b)))+\1$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EaLgr6/1)

Comment: Seems sre (and `regex` too) cannot compile this pattern, I get `error: cannot refer to an open group at position 13`.

Comment: @wim Ah I see, I tested it only on regex101 in Python. Not sure if there is a way around that. Let me check.

Comment: This is probably implemented in a different way in PyPi regex. Try passing the `regex.V1` flag and see the results, they look somewhat different than the PCRE results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that using [regex.V1](https://tio.run/##lVJBCsIwELznFUvwkGgRijeh9AcePRVlq1ELNg3bLejra1urKCaiewozs5kJGXflU2UXbVuUriIGMkdzEcIhsyELCZDc4EylS1RpglOVxWmutZ5l8UQKwabmbc3U6ZREzDMrBbxMh2HuRd8mD2hCuNfoH/OQ3Z8pvuX7IDxSH@R9WjDYJxHMhD/6@7I/v6kbqYUokXcnU/f16PsyPxR2j@ezGmsTwaMY0ShYx93WoSIYNldNGd1PUFgwtikNIRs1XhtBzUicxHo5xHBUWL6T8yNVjVNat@0N) but I don't get any output, maybe I made a mistake. I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511083/kodos-cannot-refer-to-open-group), I think it is what is stated about that the group is not closed yet.

Comment: I tried `regex.match(r'^a+(?:a(?=a*(\1?b)))+\1$', s, regex.V1)` and it yields false for `aaabb`